# cakephp, how to save data in two tables at same time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have two tables- users and employee_personals. I want to insert employee_personal.epf_no to users table at the same time when inserting employee_personal data.my code is as below

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
       $this->EmployeePersonal->create();
       $post_data = $this->request->data;
       if ($this->EmployeePersonal->save($post_data)) 
       {

          $data=$this->request->data['EmployeePersonal']['epf_no'];
          if ($this->User->save($data))
          {   
            $this->redirect(array('controller' =>'employee_personals','action'=>'add'));
          }

    }
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to save personal details'));
}
```

When i submit the form then employee_personals is inserted, but user.epf_no is empty.pls hel me to write the function

Comment: Use saveAll() instead of save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answer/comment, using saveAll() or saveAssociated() is preferable. However, if you want to proceed with your code, you need to change $data. The following should work:

```
$data['User']['epf_no'] = $this->request->data['EmployeePersonal']['epf_no'];
if ($this->User->save($data)) {...
```